# Некорректный вывод изображения Kivy

Tags: kivy, python-3.8

Пытался добавить изображения размером 30 на 30 в BoxLayout на определённой позиции с помощью этого кода:

```
image=Image(source=imagefile, x=mapx, y=mapy, size=[30, 30])
```

но получается серая мелкая линия на чёрном фоне, хотя должно быть полное серое окно, заполненное картинками. Могу ли я это сделать без использования .kv файлов?

**mapx** и **mapy** - это координаты изображения в окне (пример: 270)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему. Для начала надо было добавить `size_hint=(None, None)` для отмены уменьшения изображения.
Так же я использовал layout, на котором нельзя так просто устанавливать позицию изображения. **За место BoxLayout надо было использовать FloatLayout**